# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `questions`)

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have this problem every time i run `php artisan migrate::rollback` , but it seems okay when i run `php artisan migrate`

**Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `questions`)**

this is my migration on create_questions_table looks like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('text');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();            
    });
}

public function down()
{   
    Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    
}
```

and this is my create_users_table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

and this is my migration order, in case you want to know it
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIikb.png][1]

i will glad if anybody can help me, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run `php artisan:rollback` it didn't delete `dropForeign`

so do this

```php
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('user_id');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
}
```

---

OR as you already did rollback you can `dropForeign` in up function like this

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('user_id');

        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('text');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();            
    });
}
```

then you can run `php artisan migrate` if `foreign` already exists then only

Comment: thank you in advance, I've actually solved this problem It turns out that I created a new table that has foreign in the questions table and the new table has a typo in the up and down functions hahaha